# ZF2: po/mo generation with poEdit for Form, Validation and Filter messages

Tags: zend-framework2, poedit

I would like to translate messages contained in a configuration array:

```
    $this->add(
        [
            'name'       => 'username',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name'    => 'Regex',
                    'options' => [
                        'pattern'  => '~^[a-zA-Z\-\_0-9]+$~',
                        'messages' => [
                            Regex::NOT_MATCH =>
                                'Your username may only contain'
                                . ' letters, digits, underscores (_) and hyphens (-).'
                                . ' Please use a different one.' // Translate me
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
```

However, I could not find a way to do this with PoEdit. If this isn't possible, what is the best practice for doing this so that PoEdit can handle it?

Comment: _(' Please use a different one.') you mean something like this ?

Comment: _($string) already translates which creates an overhead, because zf2 validation messages are translated as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to write a custom method like

`function t($string) { return $string; }`

and add it to the catalogs methods.

```
Regex::NOT_MATCH =>         t('Your username may only contain'
                            . ' letters, digits, underscores (_) and hyphens (-).'
                            . ' Please use a different one.')
```

Not a beautiful solution but the only one I found to be working